# Making first element of DnD Beautiful non draggable nor droppable

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

here [here codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-beautiful-dnd-vertical-column-tasks-forked-vs8wvv)

Make This Stable at first Position (No Move Nor Drop)
Fist element of first column should not move, must stick at first position only, no drag nor drop,

[image]

first element should not be movable nor droppable, it should stick at very first positionfor `To Do` column only it should not move,
How to make this element nor movable fixed at first position
I want to use `isDropDisabled` property only for first element, and make it stick, instead its applying whole column, i dont want the first element to be dragged down,

```
    <Droppable droppableId={column.id} isDropDisabled={true}>
      {(provided, snapshot) => (
        <TaskList
          ref={provided.innerRef}
          {...provided.droppableProps}
          isDraggingOver={snapshot.isDraggingOver}
        >
          {todos.map((todo, index) => (
            <Task key={todo.id} index={index} todo={todo} />
          ))}
          {provided.placeholder}
        </TaskList>
      )}
    </Droppable>
```

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] of your code in the question itself.

Comment: @TylerH all code is added in the question and codesandbox and in working tate, the thing is i dont want first element tobe moved rest is fine, that code logic is missing in documentation itself